# Google Play show "DF-DLA-14" when try to update app which origin from GalaxyApps

Tags: android, google-play, samsung-mobile, android-signing, galaxy-apps

We have app in Samsung GalaxyApps store and in Google Play.

- User install app from GalaxyApps store
- after new update come to Google Play first
- smartphone try to install update form Google Play (though app origin from GalaxyApps - we use same package name and we don't have way to change it due to Google play billing...)
- Google Play show error **DF-DLA-14** while trying to update application.

I think, that's caused by new Google Play signing service: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423 using uploading certificate.
Samsung GalaxyApps still use normal signing certificate, not like Google Play store.

Do you have someone same issue with it who use new Google signing method using uploading jks file?

Do you have some solution for it?

I create an issue on Google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69285256